# Search Button in C# Database with access

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I Need help making a search button in C# because in Visual Basic i have this code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
    Handles Button1.Click

    Me.CostumersBindingSource.Filter = "[ID]  = ' " & Me.TextBox1.Text & "'"

End Sub
```

but i want the same for c# or any idea!!!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  All you're doing is concatenating strings.  A Google search for "C# concatenate strings" probably has some information.

Comment: You just want to convert the code to c#?

Comment: For the record, I didn't vote to close as "unclear", I voted to close as "a problem that can no longer be reproduced" (i.e. not useful Q&A for future searches, formerly known as "too localized").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be the same code in C#

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.CostumersBindingSource.Filter = "[ID]  = ' " + this.TextBox1.Text + "'";
}
```